# Consulta de varios join agrupada

Tags: mysql, laravel

Buenas tardes compañeros.

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme con esta consulta de laravel. He realizado la siguiente consulta:

```
$query = DB::table('users')
        ->join('category_user', 'users.id', '=', 'category_user.user_id')
        ->rightjoin('categories', 'category_user.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->join('complaints', 'categories.id', '=', 'complaints.category_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'categories.*', 'complaints.*')
        ->groupBy('users.id', 'categories.id', 'complaints.id')->get();
```

Mi intención es que me muestren los registros agrupados por el campo id de la tabla complaints, pero me encuentro que pueden existir registros que tienen más de un usuario relacionado. El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el ejemplo, podéis ver que el Caso-2 se repite una vez por cada usuario asignado al igual que el Caso-3.

¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos agrupados?

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Comment: como quieres agruparlos, ya estan agrupados.

Comment: Hola. Si, está agrupada pero no lo hace de forma correcta. Lo que quiero es que se muestre un registro por ID de caso y muestre los datos agrupados en el campo asignado.

No sé si lo estoy haciendo de forma correcta.

Comment: entonces usa la tabla de casos como principal y pivotea de hay a las otras ...

Comment: el problema es que hay dos personas por caso en el caso 2 ... entonces como planteas mostrar a esas dos personas??

Comment: Cierto, no es viable.

Comment: es correcto no es viable y aunque lo fuese tendrias que concatenar los nombre de las personas que esten en el mismo caso para mostarlo en una tabla se veria tambien feo ...

Comment: cuando se arman tablas hay ciertas limitaciones en como mostrar los datos... podrias ponerle un boton en la columna de personas, e invocar un modal que te muestre las personas involucradas ... puede ser que existan diferentes niveles o tipos de involucrados... y un boton no te dañaria ese layout...

Comment: con ese cambio en el diseño y funcionalidad haria viable mostrar solo un registro por caso ...

Comment: pero entonces nacen otros inconvenientes... como el querer exportar a excel esa tabla ... entonces valora bien que funcionalidad es prioritaria... antes de tomar una decicion de como mostrar el reporte

Comment: Muchas gracias por la visión y consejos. Voy a valorar lo que comentas y veo que opción tomar. Gracias.

Comment: cuando tomes una decicion y tengas dudas de como hacerlo, puedes editar esta misma pregunta, no hagas una nueva. saludos

Comment: Para estos casos yo personalmente uso la funcion GROUP_CONCAT(Asignado)